# React Native Image Memory Issue

Tags: ios, image, react-native, memory-management

I am loading many images (More than 100) Using Image component from local assets (Xcode Image assets) and showing them using swiper component [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper). The issue I am facing is every time image is loaded the memory consumption increases and its never released. How do I release the memory? what are the things I can do to improve this.

Following are the things I observed.

- All the images loaded are from Xcode Image assets
- Memory consumption increases every time new images are loaded Memory is never released until I restart the app
- Memory is not released even if parent component is popped from navigation stack
- After certain point app crashes due to
  excessive memory use.

Xcode shows no leaks just heavy memory allocation. Any help or lead will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried using [`loadMinimal` and `loadMinimalSize` props](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#custom-basic-style--content)? Can you add a [mcve] please?

Comment: @bennygenel I just tried using loadMinimal and loadMinimal size, but getting same results. I think the issue is once image is loaded in memory it is not released.

Comment: There is a prop called [`removeClippedSubviews`](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#basic-props-of-scrollview-) and it says _If true, offscreen child views (whose overflow value is hidden) are removed from their native backing superview when offscreen. This can improve scrolling performance on long lists._